# What does "appetite" means when talking about an organization?

Tags: word-meaning

ERM ensures there is a process in place to set objectives and get them aligned to organization’s mission.
This should be consistent with organization’s risk:
- appetite
- tolerance

Does "appetite" means the organization's willing?

Comment: It is a weak form of **personification**.

Comment: Did you look up *appetite* in a dictionary? What did you find?

Comment: The sentence seems incomplete. Can you provide some more of the text as context? What's the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It means how attractive the organisation finds risk-taking.